# CSS not connecting in Django

Tags: python, html, css, django

Page not found (404)
'css\static.css' could not be found
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/static.css
Raised by:  django.views.static.serve

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

settings.py:

```
"""
from pathlib import Path
import os

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'pushkin.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'pushkin.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}



LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn")

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/css'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/static.css">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav id="navigation">
        {% include "navigation.html" %}
    </nav>
    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJ3SZ.png)

Я пробовал перемещать папку static, выполнять collectstatic, и менять пути в settings и base.html

Comment: Have a look at [static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/). My guess is your `STATIC_URL`, it should be `static/` and not `/static/`. Same for `MEDIA_URL`

Comment: Solution: Run collectstatic and change <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/static.css"> to <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/static.css">

Answer (score 0):

1. Frist of all you have two static_url variables.

**STATIC_URL = '/static/'**

STATIC_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn")

**STATIC_URL = '/static/'**

2. It is bad practice / or the problem here to use
   **href="/static/css/static.css">**

You should use,

**

{% load static %}

href="{% static 'css/static.css' %}">

**

This should resolve the problem. If not, respond. I will help you.